# c puzzle(if statement)

Tags: c

what is data(number), if the required output from the following statement is is : AMAZING?

```
main()
{
 int data;
 if(data!=0 && data==-data)
 {
  printf("AMAZING");
 }
}
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_immortality

Comment: @aaronls -- Nifty link, but what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: The results are undefined and AMAZING

Answer (score 12):

It'd have to be the minimum value of an integer, i.e. 0x80000000 if it's 32-bits, because that's the only number other than zero that remains the same when negated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
 int data = 0x80000000;
 if(data!=0 && data==-data)
 {
  printf("AMAZING");
 }
}
```

Result:

```
AMAZING
```

As Richard Pennington correctly pointed out, this works because of the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of negative numbers. The largest representable positive number is one smaller in absolute value than the largest negative number, so if you try to negate the largest negative number it overflows an int and wraps around, giving back the same number.

For computers that use [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Ones.27_complement), every representable number's negative value can also be represented without overflow so this puzzle doesn't have a solution.

Comment: I tried this on my UNIVAC 1100 after adjusting for 36 bit integers (0x800000000) and it didn't work!

Comment: @Richard, according to Wikipedia for UNIVAC: Numbers were binary with negative values in one's complement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1101 So this won't work! It only works in two's complement.

Comment: @Mark: I know. Trick comment. ;-)

Comment: @Richard, Good input though, I added a bit more explanation to my comment about why and when it works.

Comment: I love the idea of an SO user rushing over to their 30 year old mainframe to try something out.

Comment: Actually, I lied. It wouldn't compile because it wouldn't accept the implicit declaration of main's return value.

Comment: OK, OK, I admit it. I don't have an 1100. I did use one once, though.

Comment: I see you had more luck than me when I used ones compliment in an answer to an interview question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832?tab=votes&page=3#849062

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the size of an integer and how integers are implemented, but on a two's complement machine with 2 byte integers, the answer is -32768.

Comment: Well, it is if you're going to go around assuming that CHAR_BIT is 8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the size of int in my machine. so I used a program to find the max value of int like

```
void main()
{
   int i;
   do{
       }while(i>i++);
   printf ("data=%d",i);
}
```

I found the max value of i = -2147483648

assign this to data this will work..

Comment: You are printing the address (`&i`) instead of the value (`i`).

Comment: i am testing this on Borland C++ 5.5.1 for windows 32 on Windows XP machine

Comment: Yea... now i understand my mistake, i really sorry for posting this, totally a big mistake from my end  :(

Comment: thanks finnw: now i corrected my mistake and able to achieve result via my own approach

Comment: Hmmmmm, when will people learn (and implement) that `main` returns an `int` to the OS, always.

Comment: Thanks Thomas: i learnt the importants of int main in program